# Angular 17 SSR Separate tsconfig for browser and server

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, angular17, angular17-ssr

In the recent versions of angular, there is only tsconfig.app.json which inherits from tsconfig.json. The file is used for the browser and server.
There is no anymore separate tsconfig.server.json.

I have installed a module that uses `document` object, which is not supported by SSR. To bypass this, I have created a stub Module, which I would like to replace in the tsconfig, in short like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "ng2-dragula": [
        "./src/app/stubs/dragula/dragula.module"
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

So the browser would use the real module, but the SSR the stub module.
However, I am not able to specify to use of a separate tsconfig for the SSR.

I use the latest Angular version 17.2.

Comment: Do you not have a server.config.ts..?

Comment: I have an `app/app.server.config.ts`

Comment: So the idea is to provide your stub module in there as an overwrite

Comment: If you mean me to use `{ provide: DraguleModule, useClass: StubDragulaModule }` - then I still import the `DraguleModule` to use in as `provide` parameter. And I still get the error `document is not defined`.

Comment: Thats why I want to replace it on a higher level - in the tsconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use a separate `tsconfig.json` for the server version of the app just because there is no separate server version anymore. But it seems that it is an A/B problem and what you want to do is to make your app using ng2-dragula work with SSR.

Here is how you can do this.
If you're using standalone components that import `DragulaModule` you can wrap them into `@defer` block so angular extracts them into separate chunks that won't be run on the server.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [WithDragulaComponent],
  template: `
    @defer{
      <app-with-dragula/>
    } @error {
      Something went wrong :(
    }`,
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-with-dragula',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DragulaModule],
  template: `
    <div class="container" dragula="DRAGULA_FACTS">
      <div>You can move these elements between these two containers</div>
      <div>Moving them anywhere else isn't quite possible</div>
      <div>There's also the possibility of moving elements around in the same container, changing their position</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrl: './with-dragula.component.scss'
})
export class WithDragulaComponent {

}
```

Don't forget to add another [ng2-dragula required](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula?tab=readme-ov-file#1-important-add-the-following-line-to-your-polyfillsts) workaround to the `main.ts`:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

Comment: 1. I had additionally to install additional packages: `dragula` and `@types/dragula`.
2. I have added `<script>var global = global || window;</script>` in the `index.html`. Did not work soltuion with `main.ts` for me.
3. Stub modules are no longer needed
4. In default setup the `appConfig` is extended by the `serverConfig`. In this case this would not work. I have created `browserConfig` (file `app.config.browser.ts`) for this to separate providers for `browser` and `server`. The `browserConfig` extends the `appConfig` and additionally provides `DragulaModule.forRoot()`. Use it in `main.ts`